# memory_limit php

Tags: php, linux, веб-сервер, php.ini, highload

в php.ini по умолчанию стоит значение 128 мб, это значение которое будет потреблять 1 сценарий или все? И имеет ли смысл ставит больше для машины с оперативкой  8гб;

Comment: Не обязательно, что будет потреблять, это максимально доступный объем для одного скрипта. Есть или нет смысла менять - зависит от ваших скриптов. Если им нужно больше 128м, значит имеет смысл.

Comment: Если скрипту нужно больше 128Мб, значит его нужно оптимизировать.

Comment: @Ипатьев иногда оптимизация по скорости вынуждает поступаться объемом потребляемой памяти (но это, конечно, специфические случаи).

Answer (score 2):

Это максимальный объем памяти, который будет потреблять один запущенный сценарий. При превышении этого значения - он будет принудительно остановлен с ошибкой

> Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of ... Bytes Exhausted

Однако, это именно максимально допустимый объем, реальный объем памяти у запущенных скриптов будет определяться их потребностью и будет меньше этого значения.